# Getting Double Precision(MatrixXd) answers using Single Precision(MatrixXf) on Eigen C++

Tags: c++, eigen, mpc

I have coded a model predictive controller on a pixhawk hardware to control the attitude (angles) of the quadcopter. I exchanged messages with one of the developers of pixhawk and he advised me to use single precision. My code is in double precision.

Before this, I tested a numerical problem with `MatrixXd` (double precision) using Eigen C++ Library and my code was able to get the same answer. I used the `ldlt()` Cholesky solver for a dense linear systems (all the other solver methods resulted in the wrong answer).

I replaced all `MatrixXd` with `MatrixXf` and `double` with `float` in order to solve the problem with single precision but I was unable to get the same answer. So I want to get some insight as to why I am not getting the same answer achieved by `MatrixXd` when I use `MatrixXf`.

Below is the relevant section. The `y` variable at the end produces the `-nan(ind); -nan(ind)` as it's solution when I declare my variables and matrices with `MatrixXf` but when I use `MatrixXd` I get the desired solution of `1; 0.9999`.

```
// Hildreth's Quadratic Programming Loop

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//i < r_cols - 1; i++)
{
    MatrixXf F = -2 * (H.transpose())*(Rs*r.col(i) - P*Xf);
    MatrixXf d = dd + dupast*uin;
    MatrixXf DeltaU = QPhild(E, F, CC, d);

    MatrixXf DeltaU_1(4, 2);
    DeltaU_1 << DeltaU(0, 0), DeltaU(1, 0),
        DeltaU(2, 0), DeltaU(3, 0),
        DeltaU(4, 0), DeltaU(5, 0),
        DeltaU(6, 0), DeltaU(7, 0);

    MatrixXf deltau = DeltaU_1.row(0);
    MatrixXf deltau_tran = deltau.transpose();
    u = u + deltau_tran;

    // Process
    x.col(i + 1) = Ad*x.col(i) + Bd*u;
    y = Cd*x.col(i + 1) + dist.col(i);

    // Model
    xh.col(i + 1) = A*xh.col(i) + B*deltau_tran + L*(y - C*xh.col(i));
    yh = C*xh.col(i + 1);

    Xf << x.col(i + 1) - x.col(i),
        y;
  }

 cout << y << endl << endl;
```

Below is the QPhild function:

```
MatrixXf QPhild(MatrixXf E, MatrixXf F, MatrixXf CC, MatrixXf d)
{
   MatrixXf CC_trans = CC.transpose();
   MatrixXf T = CC*(E.ldlt().solve(CC_trans));
   MatrixXf K = (CC*(E.ldlt().solve(F)) + d);

   int k_row = K.rows();
   int k_col = K.cols();

   MatrixXf lambda(k_row, k_col);
   lambda.setZero(k_row, k_col);

   MatrixXf al(0, 0);
   al.setConstant(10.0f);

   for (int km = 0; km < 40; km++)
   {
       MatrixXf lambda_p = lambda;

      // loop to determine lambda values for respective iterations
      for (int i = 0; i < k_row; i++)
      {
        MatrixXf t1 = T.row(i)*lambda;

        float t2 = T(i, i)*lambda(i, 0);
        float w = t1(0, 0) - t2;

        w = w + K(i, 0);
        float la = -w / T(i, i);

        if (la < 0.0f)  lambda(i, 0) = 0.0f;
        else lambda(i, 0) = la;
       }
       al = (lambda - lambda_p).transpose() * (lambda - lambda_p);

       float all = al(0, 0);
       float tol = 0.0000001f;

       if (all < tol) break;
   }

   MatrixXf DeltaU = -E.ldlt().solve(F) - (E.ldlt().solve(CC_trans))*lambda;

   return DeltaU;
}
```

I know that the main problem is from the function above because I put various `cout` lines to check outputs of various matrices within it. They start off at `0` then go to `inf` then to `nan`.

**EDIT**

Right now I am using the LLT decomposition and not LDLT (although they both give me the same answers). Regardless, I am posting the values of Matrix `E` in both double and float, with the corresponding singular values.

`Matrix E` in `double`:

```
1.84805e+12 1.65144e+12   7.557e+11 6.73531e+11 3.08645e+11 2.73966e+11 1.25821e+11 1.10981e+11
1.65144e+12 1.47576e+12 6.75306e+11 6.01881e+11 2.75811e+11 2.44823e+11 1.12436e+11 9.91757e+10
  7.557e+11 6.75306e+11  3.0902e+11  2.7542e+11 1.26211e+11  1.1203e+11 5.14507e+10 4.53824e+10
6.73531e+11 6.01881e+11  2.7542e+11 2.45475e+11 1.12488e+11 9.98504e+10 4.58567e+10 4.04488e+10
3.08645e+11 2.75811e+11 1.26211e+11 1.12488e+11 5.15474e+10  4.5756e+10 2.10137e+10 1.85354e+10
2.73966e+11 2.44823e+11  1.1203e+11 9.98504e+10  4.5756e+10 4.06159e+10 1.86529e+10 1.64534e+10
1.25821e+11 1.12436e+11 5.14507e+10 4.58567e+10 2.10137e+10 1.86529e+10 8.56643e+09  7.5562e+09
1.10981e+11 9.91757e+10 4.53824e+10 4.04488e+10 1.85354e+10 1.64534e+10  7.5562e+09 6.66534e+09
```

<strike>I cannot put all the numbers on a single line but the space between the rows is used to distinguish between different rows.</strike> Singular values of `E` in `double`:

```
3.98569e+12 5.24887e+06  1363.09  174.56  166.311  159.098  58.9402  54.5173
```

`Matrix E` in `float`:

```
1.84805e+12 1.65144e+12   7.557e+11 6.73531e+11 3.08645e+11 2.73966e+11 1.25821e+11 1.10981e+11
1.65144e+12 1.47576e+12 6.75307e+11 6.01881e+11 2.75811e+11 2.44823e+11 1.12436e+11 9.91757e+10
  7.557e+11 6.75307e+11  3.0902e+11  2.7542e+11 1.26211e+11  1.1203e+11 5.14507e+10 4.53824e+10
6.73531e+11 6.01881e+11  2.7542e+11 2.45475e+11 1.12488e+11 9.98505e+10 4.58567e+10 4.04488e+10
3.08645e+11 2.75811e+11 1.26211e+11 1.12488e+11 5.15474e+10  4.5756e+10 2.10137e+10 1.85354e+10
2.73966e+11 2.44823e+11  1.1203e+11 9.98505e+10  4.5756e+10 4.06159e+10 1.86529e+10 1.64534e+10
1.25821e+11 1.12436e+11 5.14507e+10 4.58567e+10 2.10137e+10 1.86529e+10 8.56643e+09  7.5562e+09
1.10981e+11 9.91757e+10 4.53824e+10 4.04488e+10 1.85354e+10 1.64534e+10  7.5562e+09 6.66534e+09
```

And the `float` singular values are:

```
3.98569e+12 5.08741e+06  62753.4  58133.2  26340.8  20529.1 15839.4 1050.96
```

Comment: Without looking into any details of your code, the problem likely is that you need to increase `tol` when you work with `float` instead of `double`.

Comment: I just did that, but sadly there was no change, I still got the same answer as before

Comment: Please show where exactly you get NaNs and what the values of your matrices are (i.e., provide a [mcve]!) Overall, you do lots of sub-optimal stuff, like decomposing `E` multiple times, passing matrices by value. Is your question about sparse to dense conversion related, to the `double` vs `float` problem? Otherwise, ask a separate question for that (and reduce the question to the actual problem, don't spam too much irrelevant context)

Comment: I have made some edits to the question, please let me know if it is clearer now. I have taken notice of your suggestions, I will pass my matrices by reference instead. This is my first time programming in linear algebra problems in C++, how do you propose I go about correcting multiple decompositions of `E`?

Comment: Your code is still far away from being a MCVE, neither is it minimal, nor is it compilable (as it is). Reduce your code to the part which generates the `nan` -- I don't want to debug through your code for you. Regarding decomposing `E` just once: Declare a decomposition `const Eigen::LDLT E_ldlt(E);` once and use it's `.solve()` method wherever needed.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have made it minimal but I cannot make it compilable as there are functions and variables that are needed and putting all that is essentially putting everything..about 500+ lines of code. I started trying the other methods again `llt()` gives me real numbers but they are far off about `2.6; 3.15`

Comment: As commented elsewhere: Hard to help without knowing the contents of the matrix E. If only LDLT is giving you a satisfactory result when using double, then this means there is something fishy about it. Since it seems to be small you could past it's content here (with full accuracy, both using double and float), and also print its singular-values: `cout << E.jacobiSvd().singularValues().transpose() << endl;`, again both in double and single precision.

Comment: Hello Ggael, I have made an edit to the post and added the values you requested

Comment: Your matrix is near-singular when using single precision. You should therefore use a rank-revealing decomposition, like `FullPivLU`, `ColPivHouseholderQR`, or `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`. See here for an overview of available decompositions: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html

Comment: Hello Chtz, I am not completely sure of what you wanted me to do, but this is what I did. I first of all declared this: `const ColPivHouseholderQR<MatrixXf> ColofE(E);` and used `ColofE` anytime I needed to use the `solve()` method. The answer i got fro this method is `2.65872; 3.14192` which is not close to the desired `1.00;1.00`. I tried doing the QPhild solution in `MatrixXd` then casting to `MatrixXf` but after a while it goes to infinity then `nan`.

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced teh same problem, we found out once issue, when we are converting from double to float, the rounding bring values are same sometimes. So solver results with nan. We fixed it by adding 1e-5 to differentiate the each Matrix node.

D SURESH BABU

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35680789)